# Maven layout: How to be sure that src/main does not depend on src/test?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependency-management

This must be quite elementary, but I'm fairly new to Maven and I didn't find this info.

I have the typical mavenized Java project (I use Eclipse), with a main artifact (`src/main/java` -> `mylib.jar` ) and the additional classes in `src/test/java` (not only unit tests, but also miscellanous code, samples, etc, that I don't want to include in the main jar).

My question is: how I can be sure that there are no circular dependencies inside the classes-artifacts of my project? Specifically, how can be sure that  inadvertently some class of `main` is depending on some `test\`? I'm concerned about the possibility of releasing a broken `mylib.arj`. Eclipse knows about dependency among projects, but here we have only one project. Is there some standard way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven won't actually let you do this.  Everything in the `src/test` directory structure is not on the class path when maven tries to execute the compile goal.

For instance, let's say I accidentally add the following code to my HelloWorld program:

```
public void badDependency() {
    new HelloWorld_UT();
}
```

Where `HelloWorld_UT` is just a standard junit test.

Even though eclipse will report no compile errors in my project, when I try to do a maven compile, I get this error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.297s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat May 10 23:08:29 CDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/17M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project scratch: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/eclipse/workspace/Scratch/src/main/java/org/drc/HelloWorld.java:[11,21] C:\eclipse\workspace\Scratch\src\main\java\org\drc\HelloWorld.java:11: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class HelloWorld_UT
[ERROR] location: class org.drc.HelloWorld
```

Comment: That's nice. Is there some way to make Eclipse realize that?

Comment: The only way I can think of would be to modify your project's build path to remove src/test/java from your build path and look for the red X's.  Eclipse's support for maven (even with the m2e plugin) isn't really all that great.

Answer (score 0):

Maven will automatically exclude the source code used in test when it builds the final jar. However remember to indicate with < scope>test< /scope>, if your tests have any dependencies that are not used in the main.

For example, if jUnit is used in your tests and you **don't** want to include jUnit in main, the pom.xml file for the dependencies would look like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${dependency.junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```